# If for $x\in(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ we have $f'(x)=(e^x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. Show that there exist exactly two roots of $f''(x)=0$ in the given domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Let $f:\left(\frac{1}{2},\infty \right)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f'(x)=(e^x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. Show that there exist exactly two roots of $f''(x)=0$ in the given domain.

**My Attempt**

I evaluated  $f''(x)=e^x(x-2)(x-3)+(e^x-1)(x-2)+(e^x-1)(x-3)$ and then plugged in the values
$1,2$ and $3$ and obtained

$f''(1)=3-e>0$

$f''(2)=(e^2-1)(-1)<0$

$f''(3)=e^3-1>0$

So one can observe that there is at least one root on both of the intervals $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

But how does one claim that there are exactly two roots in the given domain

Comment: Why don't you rolle's thrm on [0,2] and [2,3]?

Comment: $x=0$ is not in the given domain

Comment: You can extend the function into [0, infty] and then show that there is no root in [ 0 , 1/2] , right?

Comment: What is wrong with just noting that $f'$ the signs in the intervals $(1/2,2) \cup (2,3) \cup (3,\infty)$? You have $+-+$ implying two zeros, no?

Comment: In case it helps, $f''(x) = e^x(x^2 - 3x + 1) - 2x + 5$.

Comment: And solving numerically gives the roots as 1.0376307444722144 and 2.6261696260112686.